# Applications for the Church Programming Language

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, church-pl

Has anyone worked with the programming language [Church](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/church/wiki/Church)? Can anyone recommend practical applications? I just discovered it, and while it sounds like it addresses some long-standing problems in AI and machine-learning, I'm skeptical. I had never heard of it, and was surprised to find it's actually been around for a few years, having been announced in the paper [Church: a language for generative models](http://uai.sis.pitt.edu/displayArticleDetails.jsp?mmnu=2&smnu=2&author_id=1398&article_id=1346).

Comment: At best, discussion questions should be marked as community wiki.  Most of the time they are not the appropriate format for Stack Overflow.

Comment: After reading through the project's wiki and docs, it's clear this is just another toy language with no serious future. None of the examples were specific to Church, and could easily be duplicated in nearly any language. The articles that brought this to my attention clearly overhyped and misrepresented the scope of the project. Vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what to say about the matter of practical applications.  Does modeling cognitive abilities with generative models constitute a "practical application" in your mind?

The key importance of Church (at least right now) is that it allows those of us working with probabilistic inference solutions to AI problems a simpler way to model.  It's essentially a subset of Lisp.

I disagree with Chris S that it is at all a toy language.  While some of these inference problems can be replicated in other languages (I've built several in Matlab) they generally aren't very reusable and you really have to love working in 4 and 5 for loops deep (I hate it).

Instead of tackling the problem that way, Church uses the recursive advantages of lamda calaculus and also allows for something called memoization which is really useful for generative models since your generative model is often not the same one trial after trial--though for testing you really need this.

I would say that if what you're doing has anything to do with Bayesian Networks, Hierarchical Bayesian Models, probabilistic solutions to POMDPs or Dynamic Bayesian Networks then I think Church is a great help.  For what it's worth, I've worked with both Noah and Josh (two of Church's authors) and no one has a better handle on probabilistic inference right now (IMHO).

Comment: Lamda calaculus has been implemented in dozens of libraries for several languages. And memoization is a design pattern that's as old as time. There's nothing new here. I'm still not clear on why they felt they needed to invent Yet Another Lisp Dialect instead of just using Common Lisp or Scheme.

Comment: Cerin, the point of the language is neither lambda calculus per se, or memoization, but the ability to represent a probabilistic model of the "world", by writing a program that simulates it, and then asking questions about how likely specific events are.For example, if you write a program describing how 3D objects are projected into a 2D image, you could ask: given this image, what are the 3D objects that generated it? That is, you go from a relatively simple image projection problem to the much harder *vision* problem, automatically. You give *output* and get *input*, with probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Church is part of the family of probabilistic programming languages that allows the separation of the estimation of a model from its definition. This makes probabilistic modeling and inference a lot more accessible to people that want to apply machine learning but who are not themselves hardcore machine learning researchers.

For a long time, probabilistic programming meant you'd have to come up with a model for your data and derive the estimation of the model yourself: you have some observed values, and you want to learn the parameters. The structure of the model is closely related to how you estimate the parameters, and you'd have to be pretty advanced knowledge of machine learning to do the computations correctly. The recent probabilistic programming languages are an attempt to address that and make things more accessible for data scientists or people doing work that applies machine learning.

As an analogy, consider the following:

> You are a programmer and you want to run some code on a computer. Back in the 1970s, you had to write assembly language on punch cards and feed them into a mainframe (for which you had to book time on) in order to run your program. It is now 2014, and there are high-level, simple to learn languages that you can write code in even with no knowledge of how computer architecture works. It's still helpful to understand how computers work to write in those languages, but you don't **have** to, and many more people write code than if you had to program with punch cards.

Probabilistic programming languages do the same for machine learning with statistical models. Also, Church isn't the only choice for this. If you aren't a functional programming devotee, you can also check out the following frameworks for Bayesian inference in graphical models:

- [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/default.aspx), written in C# by the [Microsoft Research lab in Cambridge, UK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/labs/cambridge/)
- [stan](http://mc-stan.org/), written in C++ by the Statistics department at Columbia

Answer (score -1):

You know what does a better job of describing Church than what I said? This MIT article: http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2010/ai-unification.html

It's slightly more hyperbolic, but then, I'm not immune to the optimism present in this article.

Answer (score -9):

Likely, the article was intended to be published on April Fool's Day.
Here's another article dated late march of last year.  http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/44963